# how to get all the pages inside a site?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

How to get all the pages inside a site? I will pass the parameter of a site in a site collection example: `http://www.category.com/en`,using powershell code in sharepoint server 2013.

when i  try below command i can not get all sites under a site

```
Get-SPSite  https://xxxx/xx  -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs
```

Comment: Pages or subsites?

Comment: hi i wants to get all pages in a site and its sub sites

Comment: Pages as in the actual aspx pages in the library pages/site pages? The above is trying to get all the site collections in the farm and its subsites.

Comment: yes ,i need subsites list in a site and pages

Answer (score 2):

This might be a starting point for you:

```
$site = Get-SPSite https://sharepoint.contoso.com

# This is enough to select all webs in site collection, you don't need to select AllWebs
$webs = Get-SPWeb -Site $site -Limit ALL

# Iterate all webs
foreach ($web in $webs) {
    # Get SitePages library. If you have multiple libraries or use publishing,
    # you need to execute it for all libraries.
    $sitePages = $web.Lists.EnsureSitePagesLibrary()
    # This will only get files from root folder. You can use $folder.SubFolders to get all files
    $sitePages.RootFolder.Files | Select ServerRelativeUrl
}
```